# Android method onClick doesn't start until another onClick method completes?

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, onclicklistener

Currently my onClickListener for two Buttons 'play' and 'stop' is common and the onClick method is as follows

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.play:
                play();
                break;

            case R.id.stop:
                stop();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Is there any way for stop() to be run at the same time play() is running? Should I use threads to make the two onClick methods run simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

No, they will not run at the same time because button clicks are handled on main thread. You need to call that method from different threads if You want to start them at the same time.